# Upgrade Azure docker extension

Tags: azure, ssl, docker, docker-machine

I am trying to use `docker-machine` to manage the docker instance running in our VM. I had started the VM a while back, and I believe had also installed docker via the "Azure Docker extension".

When I try to set things up with `docker-machine`, I noticed that I didn't have the certs on my laptop. Logging in to the VM, I found out that there are no certs in `/etc/docker`. I also noticed that the docker image on the server is pretty old (`1.8.1`).

How can I upgrade docker to the latest version on this VM? Would I lose my VMs if I did so? I'm not sure how to deal with this "Azure Docker extension".

Would this also re-generate the certs in `/etc/docker`, so that I can set up `docker-machine`?

Answer (score 0):

One way to update the certs from the Azure portal : you can add the docker extension again on your VM and in the extension options you can specify the new certificates you want to use. You will probably also have to reboot the VM after re-applying the extension to make it work properly.